# Copy Activity with REST Linked Service as Sink with MS Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

I basically have the same issue as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162229/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-rest-api-(as-sink) person.

What I'm trying to do is, update my AD with the Graph API by having a Copy activity that has my database as the source and the REST dataset using Graph as my sink.

I tried mapping it from $.dataValue to even doing a dynamic content using json function with @json({ property: value}). I cannot seem to get the data to go through. Now in a web activity the latter works. But I was hoping the Copy activity would be much faster. I'm getting this error 99% of the time: "Empty Payload. JSON content expected." Any guidance is appreciated.

For example: my DB source is as so:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "10",
            "FirstName": "John",
            "Middlename": "A",
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "DisplayName": "Johnny",
            "Email": "JohnDoe@gmail.com",
            "LocCountry": "US",
            "LocStreet": "123 Street",
            "LocCity": "Los Angeles",
            "LocState": "CA",
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "IRCore (West US)",
    "billingReference": {
    ...
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

In the sink I've tried:
[image: Sink side]

The default mapping is this, but doesn't work:
[image: Sink Default]

Comment: Update the Qs with clear ask and details of effort taken along with error/blocker.

Comment: @AnalyzingTasks, you have given lookup output to mapping of the copy activity? can you provide what it is resulting?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula, it gives me that error that I posted in my initial post, "Empty Payload. JSON content expected". So I don't know if I'm supposed to do an extra mapping TO the Sink from Source to Name, I'd expected to map them according to the Graph names such as: city, state, userPrincipalName, etc. But even that doesn't work and I get the same error message I just provided.